# Rails Get State from ZIP Geoip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geoip

I have the zip code of the user that they entered and would like to pre-populate a few fields with the city/state. Does anyone know of a good way to get this information? I want to do something like this:

```
GeoIP.new('geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat').zip('53593')
```

I know I could do `GeoIP.new('geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat').city(request.remote_ip)` but that's where they are at the time as opposed to where they may actually live.

Comment: Link to this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the [`geoip`](https://rubygems.org/gems/geoip) Ruby gem ([Github repo](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip/)) has the ability to search by zip / postal code. When scanning [the geoip.rb source](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip/blob/master/lib/geoip.rb), there is no method for `zip` or `postal_code`.

There is another gem, [`my_zipcode_gem`](https://rubygems.org/gems/my_zipcode_gem), that you may be able to use. This is also [hosted on Github](https://github.com/midwire/my_zipcode_gem) and has the following syntax:

```
zipcode = Zipcode.find_by_code '66206'
zipcode.state.abbr    # => 'KS'
zipcode.city          # => 'Shawnee Mission'
zipcode.county.name   # => 'Johnson'
zipcode.lat.to_s      # => '38.959356', it is actually a BigDecimal object converted to_s for documentation.
zipcode.lon.to_s      # => '-94.716155', ditto
zipcode.is_geocoded?  # => true, most if not all should be pre-geocoded.
```

Comment: What country or countries are you interested in?

Comment: USA and Canada only